# Support on disabling debug and info logs of Springboot and hibernate when hosted on AWS Lambda

Tags: java, spring-boot, aws-lambda, log4j2, slf4j

We have hosted a springboot application to AWS lambda. We are receiving huge logs which is not expected. We have tried the following ways to optimize our logs

https://www.baeldung.com/java-enterprise-aws-lambda
https://mkyong.com/spring-boot/spring-boot-test-how-to-stop-debug-logs/

None of the above seems to work. We are getting the springboot and hibernate logs as usual(huge).

We have tested the same using Log4j as well as SLF4j . Even this did not work.

Kindly suggest how the logs can be optimized.

Comment: Instead of providing links, show us what you tried. Spring Boot by default uses Logback, so trying log4j config won't work. If you don't have an explicit config file specifying the levels in the `application.[properties|yaml]` will work. Unless you start with `--debug` or `--trace` that will override those.

Answer (score 0):

As it was said in the comment spring uses Logback as a default.
Still you can add log4j support by replacing the logging adapter e.g. in maven:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
    <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-logging</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
</dependency>

<!-- Add Log4j2 Dependency -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-log4j2</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

You can then just configure a standard Log4j2 as usual by placing a `log4j2.xml` in  `src/main/resources`.
If you want to have fancy logging in JSON out of the box you can also use the [Powertools AWS Java](https://awslabs.github.io/aws-lambda-powertools-java/core/logging/). These give you best practises out of the box also to make your logs searchable.